# How to detect, if a virtual machine has changed in OpenVZ?

Tags: backup, debian, openvz

I want to backup my virtual machines (all Debian) with a cronjob. As the backups per machine can be pretty huge I only want to backup the system with its configuration itself (leaving out the directory where users mess around), which can be done with the exclude-dir-parameter.

I'm planning to run the cronjob once a week. But I really only want to backup the machine if something has changed in the system configuration or new packages have been installed. Is there a way to detect such changes in a virtual machine before running vzdump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done rather simply.

I version control all my containers with [git](http://git-scm.com/).

You can start like this (everything is done on the head node):

```
apt-get install git-core
cd /srv/vz/private
git init
```

At this point you need to write a good [.gitignore](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitignore.html) file:

```
vi .gitignore
```

My looks like this:

```
var
srv
tmp
home
```

Check to make sure you did not miss anything in your ignore list:

```
git status
```

To make a commit, do this:

```
git add .
git commit -a
```

To check if anything changed, run:

```
git status
```

Comment: Interesting approach, seems like a good idea. Thank you!

Comment: I've just started with git though - it is not a problem to have that many files versioned?

Comment: With git you can version Gigabytes with 10,000s of files - all operations (even merging) will complete in seconds. Here are some measurements that I did http://biocluster.ucr.edu/~alevchuk/git-test.txt - I predict that Git will scale to 100s of Gigabytes and 1,000,000s of files and  the run times for all git operations will stay under 5 minutes on a decent storage (directly attached).